# looking for a way to highlight duplicates across a data set in different colors

Tags: excel

I have sequential columns of data, each has a list of ID codes.

I would like to highlight duplicates across columns, but in order to keep everything straight it would be amazing if I could highlight each duplicate in a different color.

i.e. If 12345 appears in columns 2, 4, and 8, and 23456 appears in 1, 2, and 4, then I'd like to have 12345 highlighted in red in all locations, and 23456 highlighted in yellow in all locations. Ideally then each subsequent duplicate would also need to be highlighted in a new color.

I'm wondering if there's any way to set this up in excel using built in functionality. If not, I promise I'll post a guide displaying how to do it with VBA, but I wanted to check first before I go through all that work.

Comment: look at conditional formatting based on countifs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this VBA approach.

```
Sub ColorsDuplicateNum()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cel As Range
Dim Cel2 As Range
Dim Colors As Long

Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K500")
Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Colors = 3
For Each Cel In Rng
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cel) > 1 And Cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
Set Cel2 = Rng.Find(Cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not Cel2 Is Nothing Then
        Firstaddress = Cel2.Address
        Do
        Cel.Interior.ColorIndex = Colors
        Cel2.Interior.ColorIndex = Colors
            Set Cel2 = Rng.FindNext(Cel2)

        Loop While Firstaddress <> Cel2.Address
    End If
Colors = Colors + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Adjust `Range("A1:K500")` to your range of cells. Colors are starting from 3 in order to skip Black and White color.